# Symfony 1 Doctrine query in query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I need to write 2 nested queries like so:

```
SELECT * from table1 t1 WHERE t1.value1 = 5 AND t1.id IN (
  SELECT t2.id FROM t2 LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.id = t3.t2_id WHERE ....
)
```

The problem is that Query1 and nested query Query2 are doctrine query objects, so if I do:

```
$q1->where('t1.id IN ('.$q2->getSqlQuery().')', $q2->getFlattenedParams())
```

it does not work, since the component names need to match definition;

```
$q1->getSqlQuery()
```

returns the actual table names, while $q1->where expects the component names of t2 and t3 as defined in the schema.yml

So how can I achieve the required query (without running 2 separate queries and use PHP to generate the where in array from the results of $q2).

Answer (score 0):

So far this works for me:

```
$q1->where('t1.id IN ('.$q2->getDql().')', $q2->getFlattenedParams());
```

Please let me know if I'm missing something